# Connect multiple time points over time with geom_segment() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-curve

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
tree=data.frame(time=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2), pop.size=c(10,10,10,14,13,10,17,24,13), 
                parents=c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,1,2,3), offspring=c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,7))
```

I would like at each time point to plot the offspring as dots with geom_point and connect
them with their parents at the previous time point using geom_segment() or any other geom that might be useful.

```
ggplot(tree,aes(x=time, y=offspring))+
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
While I can connect the points of time point 1 with time point 2, its hard to do connect the time point 2 with 3. I have to tell you that I have up to 100 points

EDIT:
I would like to see something like this. Here I connect only elements of time point 1 with the elements of time point 2. I would like to connect time point 2 with time  point 3 and my plot look like a genealogical tree

```
ggplot(tree,aes(x=time, y=offspring))+
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=time[1], xend=time[5], y=parents, yend=offspring))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
ggplot(tree,aes(x=time, y=offspring,group=time))+geom_line()+
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or:

```
ggplot(tree,aes(x=time, y=offspring,group=1))+geom_line()+
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Update**

Try this code:

```
tree %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(ind = 1:length(time)) -> tree2
ggplot(tree2,aes(x=time, y=offspring,group=ind))+geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Duck thank you for your time. I think I was not clear with my post for this I edited.

Comment: @LDT I have updated the solution. Please check and let me know if this works!